# Data stuck in kafka queues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have a Nifi template in which consumekafka is  a processor and it sends data to elasticsearch but data is stuck in between the queues. Can anyone please tell what is reason that data is stuck in nifi queue and how can I resove it?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that any processors inbetween the ConsumeKafka and Sending to Elastic are not running properly. Or it could be that the data is only scheduled to run in X amount of time, with X being a large number. But that's just a guess based upon the information provided. Or it could be an error with a processor being used.

Comment: It was because the queue capacity was less as compared to size of data which was passing at a time, so I just added more nodes of Nifi and changed some queue settings.